# manipulating active directory with PHP?

Tags: windows-server-2003, php, active-directory

I'm looking to automate some repetitive active directory tasks but I don't care for .NET.  I'm curious if anyone has used a language such as PHP to interact with a windows active directory environment and manipulate users?

Comment: whats wrong with .net its not a language.  So with php your still mostly likely going to be using .net underneath things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the all my link on this system, but I know users objects can be managed via PHP and many other things.  But there is important consideration.  The active directory will not allow you to modify anything about passwords via LDAP unless SSL is enabled.  This means you must have a DomainController SSL certificate installed on the DC, and it may mean you need to setup a CA infrastructure.

- PHP AD Password changing.

  - http://www.letu.edu/people/markroedel/netcccu/activedirectorypasswordchanges.htm

Comment: I notice that a Drupal module, which is PHP-based claims, as one of its features, the ability to provision ldap accounts, and some of the comments mention active directory.  http://drupal.org/project/issues/ldap_provisioning?categories=All

Answer (score 0):

looks like PHP has the ability built in with openLDAP!  Here's the manual I found.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php

Comment: Naked LDAP is not AD, so it very much depends on what the tasks are.